# Get category name by category id without if else statement

Tags: laravel-5

```
public function shirts($type = '') {
  {
    if ($type == 'glass') {
      $shirt = Product::where('category_id', '1') - > get();
    }
    elseif($type == 'ic') {
      $shirt = Product::where('category_id', '2') - > get();
    }
    elseif($type == 'cover') {
      $shirt = Product::where('category_id', '3') - > get();
    } else {
      $shirt = Product::all();
    }
    $products = Category::find($shirt);
    return view('front.shirt', compact('products', 'shirt'));
  }
}
```

can some one help me in minimising this Controller I don't want to use if else statement

Comment: please post your code in readable format

Comment: first you are using brackets twice in function. as you are using the find method for category it suppose to return only one data! can you explain a bit more with so will be helpful to help you

Comment: I have to find only one value but have to categories on different clicks that is    like in category I am using women and men so I have to get men category on first if statement and women on else if statement

Comment: Not sure why you cant pass category id rather then name of a category. Suerly you have some sort of search. Why dont you send category Id in the request and you will avoid using all the if else block of code. And also I think you need to create relationship between `category` and `product` so it will be easy for you to get all the products for specific category just by doing `Category::find($request->get('categoryId'))->first()->products`

Comment: can some one help me in minimising this Controller I don't want to use if else statement